# How can set a shuffle status with array in discord.js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js, status

I want to set my discord bot's activity shuffle messages that i have to get from an array.
I've tested this code but it will only shows the last one in array or just first and last sometimes :

```
    const array = [
  {
    id: '08933438391',
    type: 'ejx1'
  },
  {
    id: '12361425430',
    type: 'ejx3'
  },
  {
    id: '63746455430',
    type: 'ejx2'
  },
  {
    id: '83972535430',
    type: 'ejx4'
  }
]
setInterval(() => {
const aa = [
     { type: 'PLAYING', message: array.type }
];
const presence = aa[Math.floor(Math.random() * aa.length)];
client.user.setActivity(presence.message, { type: presence.type });
}, 10000);
```

And this is my array :

```
    [
  {
    id: '08933438391',
    type: 'ejx1'
  },
  {
    id: '12361425430',
    type: 'ejx3'
  },
  {
    id: '63746455430',
    type: 'ejx2'
  },
  {
    id: '83972535430',
    type: 'ejx4'
  }
]
```

**Thank you for your helps.**

Comment: Can you show the place where you declare the `array` variable?

Comment: Your aa array only have one element so it seems logical to return the same. Maybe you should be using your "array" instead for the random selection. I can't help you without the whole code.

Comment: @Caladan My array variable is declared before the  aa variable

Comment: @Dorian349 This is my whole code I mean the rest are discord.js defaults

Comment: The `array` variable has multiple values. Hence using `array.type` wouldn't give you anything but an error unless you are using `.forEach()`. And since I am not seeing any `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in your code, that might be why you are seeing only the last element in the array as the status as it has gone through all the other ones already

Comment: @Caladan oh you mean that. I edited my code and I used setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: either pick a random element from an array at every interval or loop through all of them and once all the elements are done, then start again:

- **Method 1**: To do this all you have to add is a random element generator in the `setInterval()` function to pick a random element from the array, then you can just apply it by using this:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    const randomElement = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    const aa = [
        { 
            type: 'PLAYING', 
            message: randomElement.type 
        }
    ];
    client.user.setActivity(aa.message, { type: aa.type });
}, 10000);
```

- **Method 2**: For this method, you have to keep a counter outside of the `setInterval()` function and then increment it every time the function runs. Once the counter reaches a certain number, then reset it back to 0. An example:

```js
let counter = 0
setInterval(() => {
    const aa = [
        { 
            type: 'PLAYING', 
            message: array[counter].type 
        }
    ];
    client.user.setActivity(aa.message, { type: aa.type });
    counter++;
    counter = counter === array.length - 1 ? 0 : counter
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
  {
    id: '08933438391',
    type: 'ejx1'
  },
  {
    id: '12361425430',
    type: 'ejx3'
  },
  {
    id: '63746455430',
    type: 'ejx2'
  },
  {
    id: '83972535430',
    type: 'ejx4'
  }
]
setInterval(() => {
  const aa = [
    { type: 'PLAYING', message: messageArray[0].type }
  ]
  const presence = messageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * messageArray.length)]
  client.user.setActivity(presence.message, { type: presence.type })
}, 10000)
```

Comment: You didn't use `aa` variable, and there is no `message` in `messageArray` it's just id and type. I think you forgot to rename `aa` to `messageArray` right? Thank you

Comment: And if im right, it's gonna show just first one I mean just `ejx1` cause you said `messageArray[0].type`

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use `aa` variable
just do it like this:

```
 setInterval(() => {
    const presence = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    client.user.setActivity(presence.type, { type: "PLAYING });
    }, 10000);
```

and don't forget this will return a random type, and you may take 4 ejx1 in a row